# Как использовать кириллицу в LaTex на Java?

Tags: java, javafx, latex

Что нужно сделать что бы при создание Word документа в формулах была видно русская кириллица? Использую библиотеку spire doc

```
    public void firstFormula(String t,double t1,String t3){
    Paragraph paragraph = section.addParagraph();
    String[] latexMathCode = {
            "\\sigma_{"+"раст"+"}= ",
            "\\sigma_{ekv}",
            "\\cdot",
            "n_{\\sigma}",
            " = "+t+
                    "\\cdot"+ t1," = "+t3
    };

    OfficeMath officeMath;
    for (int i = 0; i < latexMathCode.length; i++) {
        officeMath = new OfficeMath(document);
        officeMath.fromLatexMathCode(latexMathCode[i]);
        paragraph.getItems().add(officeMath);

    }
}
```

Сейчас он вместо индекса "раст" пишет хххх

Comment: Может, [это](http://dkhramov.dp.ua/Comp.CyrillicInFormulaTeX) чем-то поможет?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил обратившись на сайт разработчика. Для решения проблемы достаточно использовать последнюю версию spire.doc.